# Can highcharts crosshairs show on top of area chart fill?

Tags: highcharts

Can the cross-hairs for Highcharts show on top of the area chart instead of being hidden beneath it?
Here's an example of the problem [jsfiddle.net/hHjZb/1286/](http://jsfiddle.net/hHjZb/1286/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:**
Highcharts has now implemented [the OP's feature request](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1887819-allow-changing-z-index-of-crosshair).  You can now specify the `zIndex` in the `tooltip` property.  Like:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: [ {
        width: 1,
        color: 'lime',
        zIndex: 22
        }, {
        width: 1,
        color: 'lime',
        zIndex: 22
    } ]
},
```

---

At the time of this question, Highcharts did not give us a way to do that. Not even CSS styles can change the plot order (visibility).
Consider making a [feature request](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general). (Update: the FR was made and implemented.)

Meanwhile, you can tweak the Highcharts source (in that example, it is [highcharts.com/js/testing.js](http://highcharts.com/js/testing.js)).

Find this line in the source file:

```
attribs = {
    'stroke-width': crosshairsOptions[i].width || 1,
    stroke: crosshairsOptions[i].color || '#C0C0C0',
    zIndex: 2
};
```

and change the `zIndex` to 20.

Then find this line in the source file:

```
var group = renderer.g('tooltip')
    .attr({ zIndex: 8 })
    .add(),
```

and change the `zIndex` to 22.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `zIndex` attribute for crosshairs:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: [{
        width: 3,
        color: 'green',
        zIndex: 50
    }, {
        width: 3,
        color: 'green',
        zIndex: 50
    }]
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hHjZb/3711/